# convert the following html inline style attributes to css

Tags: html, css

I designed a web page using bootstrap studio and all the style attributes are inline. I want to change this and add these to a separate css file. I have trouble doing that, because when i add the image as 'background-image:url('img/pic.jpg'); it doesn't show up.  And i don't know how to convert all the following attributes . The following is the code.

```
<div class="intro-body" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(8,1,36) 40%, transparent 49%), url(&quot;assets/img/0274207612d515f49012c87803a9e631.gif?h=eaa5e6b00c67acb1f616e82b147e0137&quot;) right / contain repeat-x;filter: brightness(120%) contrast(102%) hue-rotate(342deg) invert(0%) saturate(95%);">
```

for example what I want is ,
if html code is `<div class="intro" style="width:500px;height:400px;">`
the code for the separate css should be

```
.intro
{
width:500px;
height:400px;
}
```

Comment: do u want to know about build tool that can do such stuff for u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in your css file as you did in your question

```
.intro
{
width:500px;
height:400px;
}
```

But note to use the right class name in your example it would be

```
<div class="intro-body"> // and not "intro"
```

```css
.intro-body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(8, 1, 36) 40%, transparent 49%), url(&quot;assets/img/0274207612d515f49012c87803a9e631.gif?h=eaa5e6b00c67acb1f616e82b147e0137&quot;) right / contain repeat-x;
  filter: brightness(120%) contrast(102%) hue-rotate(342deg) invert(0%) saturate(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-body">"</div>
```

Then in your `.html` file you have to include the css file. Add the following line in the head section of your html document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstyle.css">
```

*Note:* Be careful at the href attribute it depends on the filestructure you have in your project.

For instance when your index.html file is in the base folder and the css file is in the directory /styles

- index.html
- styles

  - yourstyle.css

Then you have to write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/yourstyle.css"> inside your index.html file
```

Answer (score 2):

just copy the inline css and paste this code in css with your class sector `.intro-body`

```css
.intro-body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(8,1,36) 40%, transparent 49%), url(assets/img/0274207612d515f49012c87803a9e631.gif) right / contain repeat-x;
  filter: brightness(120%) contrast(102%) hue-rotate(342deg) invert(0%) saturate(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-body"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, But the image still doesn't show up. The image path is correct. will you be able to tell me if the problem is with my browser or anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

I think you have put css in seperate folder so you are having this issue.

After Separating your css, Change url to relative values.

ie. url('img/pic.jpg') to url('./img/pic.jpg')

```css
.intro-body {
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(8,1,36,0.4), transparent 49%), url('./img/pic.jpg') right / contain repeat-x;
  filter: brightness(120%) contrast(102%) hue-rotate(342deg) invert(0%) saturate(95%);
}
```

```html
<body >
    <div class="intro-body"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: oh .. yes.. the path is wrong. the css file is in a separate folder named css. and the image is in a separate folder called img.  How should i link the image? Thanks btw

Comment: in stylesheet use url as '../img/yourimage.png'

../ comes back 1 folder and refers file from that location.

Answer (score 0):

create separate css file and include your css file to html page as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
```

add your css to that file as shown below.

```
.intro-body {
    /*your css goes here*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the folder structure is :
FolderProject/css/style.css for the css
FolderProject/index.html for the html
FolderProject/assets/img/

The css file:

```
.intro-body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(8,1,36) 40%, transparent 49%), url(&quot;../assets/img/0274207612d515f49012c87803a9e631.gif?h=eaa5e6b00c67acb1f616e82b147e0137&quot;) right / contain repeat-x;
  filter: brightness(120%) contrast(102%) hue-rotate(342deg) invert(0%) saturate(95%);
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="intro-body">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```